# Updating an xml sitemap with c#

Tags: c#, xml, sitemap

I have a google sitemap. Sometimes I need to update that sitemap.
I was wondering if there was a way to use C# to change the details of what is set in the sitemap.

I can read it and create it, but I would like to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found :

```
XDocument sitemap = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
                    List<XElement> siteElements = (from site in sitemap.Root.Elements(xmlNs + "url")
                                            where ((string)site.Element(xmlNs + "loc") ?? string.Empty).EndsWith(test.Btw.ToString())
                                            select site).ToList();
foreach (var siteElement in siteElements)
{
    siteElement.ReplaceWith(
        new XElement(xmlNs + "url",
            new XElement(xmlNs + "loc",
                string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}{1}", test.Taal == EnumTaal.Nl ? NlDomain : FrDomain,
                test.ToCompanyVat())),
            new XElement(xmlNs + "lastmod", string.Format("{0}", test.LastMod)),
            new XElement(xmlNs + "priority", "0.5")
            )
        );
    }

    sitemap.Save(file.FullName);
```

This works perfectly.